# How to show error message when field is required and it's value is empty?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, material-design, material-ui

I am using this [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-material-ui-form-validator) to validate my form. I want to show error message on `button` when .click happens. In my form all fields are `required` so I need to validate my form.

I tried with below code but doesn't work

```
<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
            <TextValidator
              required
              InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true
              }}
              id="name"
              label="search value"
              name="searchValue"
              value={searchValue}
              onChange={event => handleInput(event, "searchValue")}
              validators={["required"]}
              errorMessages={["this field is required"]}
              margin="normal"
            />
          </FormControl>
```

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/l40l795vx7

```
<SearchForm
          handleInput={this.handleInputFieldChange}
          submitClick={this.submitButtonClickHandle}
          form={form}
        />
```

Comment: You should probably expand on what "_but doesn't work_" means... for example, does it reject the input but not show any message, or does it accept the invalid (missing) input (or something else entirely)?

Comment: @TripeHound it is not showing error message when I click on button

Comment: you can simply use component state and material-ui formControl

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are tying to validate in there, since I'm not familiar with the plugin. However, its quite easy to display an error in case of the form not being valid.

You are already saving the `values` from the `inputs` in the `state`, so all you have to do in the `submitButtonClickHandle` function is something like:

```
if(this.state.form.searchValue !== '**some conditions**' && 
this.state.form.circle !== '**some condition**'){
 //
 alert('You did not meet the search criteria')

} else {
// DO WHAT YOU WANT IF ON THE SUBMIT
alert('everything is fine, here is your result')
}
```